# How to count the number of currently connected Protocols in Python twisted framework

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I was trying to count the number of active protocols in twisted but i got an error:

```
exceptions.AttributeError: Factory instance has no attribute 'numProtocols'
```

Below is the code:

```
class EchoPro(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.numProtocols = self.factory.numProtocols+1
        if self.factory.numProtocols > 100:
            self.transport.write("Too many connections, try later")
            self.transport.loseConnection()
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.numProtocols = self.factory.numProtocols-1

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `self.factory` does not contain the `numProtocols` attribute.

To customise the protocol's factory you create a Factory for your protocol by subclassing `twisted.internet.protocol.Factory`.

Example:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Echo(Protocol):
    # ... your implementation as it is now ...

class EchoFactory(Factory):  # Factory for your protocol
    protocol = Echo
    numProtocols = 0

factory = EchoFactory()
factory.protocol = Echo

reactor.listenTCP(8007, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Alternatively, you could just modify the factory instance once it is created, [as done in the docs](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/core/howto/servers.html#auto5).

Example:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Echo(Protocol):
    # ... your implementation as it is now ...

def getEchoFactory():
    factory = Factory()
    factory.protocol = Echo
    factory.numProtocols = 0
    return factory

reactor.listenTCP(8007, getEchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```